# VS Code Vim mode (open file under cursor)

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

when I use "open file under cursor" in VIM eg. @include('partials.card') there are no problems, you jump to file and everything works as expected, but the same does not work i VS Code VIM mode unless full filename is specified eg. @include('partials/card.blade.php'). Is there a workaround for this beside putting the whole filename?

Comment: Does VS Code support vim’s `includeexpr` option?

Comment: not sure Ben but I found acceptable workaround

Comment: instead of editing the question with a solution, it is preferred to put an answer with your solution. I’ll rollback your edits; you can still find the text in the edit history to put in an answer.